# Modifying OpsWeb frontend

Tags: docker, frontend

I am working with OpsWeb, an application based on docker containers.
I want to modify how the opsweb GUI looks like, and to do so I need to modify the frontend code.
I have access to the code, but I cannot commit changes to the original repository, so I decided to fork the original repo, and modify the code manually.

Since opsweb is based on docker, I suppose that I need to create a new image for the frontend container, because otherwise the docker compose file will always take the image from the "standard" frontend code.
The problem is that I run into errors when building the image, in particular when running a command in the docker file that should copy a json file: this json file is in the right building environment, so in the same folder as the Dockerfile, but still it seems like it cannot be found.

Do you have other solutions? It is the first time for me working in this complicated combination of containers and forked repositories.